# Postgres - Create a table with foreign keys from another database

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys

I am working on postgres, I have 2 databases in the same server/instance, DB1 and DB2.

In DB2 I have my schema1.person table

```
Create table schema1.person (
  person_id int primary key,
  name varchar(20)
);
```

In DB1 I have this table

```
Create table schemaX.orders (
OrderId int primary key,
notes text,
person_id,
CONSTRAINT "fk person.id to order.person" 
  FOREIGN KEY (person_id) REFERENCES "DB2".schema1.person (person_id)
)
```

orders has a fk from another database, and when I ran this showed me this error on PG-ADMIN:

> ERROR:  cross-database references are not implemented: "DB2"
> SQL state: 0A000

Any idea how I can solve this issue? and make fk from different databases, I have more tables with this scenario.

Comment: No, that's not possible. You need to move all tables into the same database (in different schemas)

Comment: Hi @a_horse_with_no_name , i read about this https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/postgres-fdw.html this update the destination table automatically?